# Using Canvas, how to draw a shape X-times entered by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw 30 rectangles and the n-th rectangle is the number entered by the user. Every n-th rectangle will be a color entered by the user. Here's what I have below:

```js
<script> 
let n = document.getElementById("number")
let colors = document.getElementById("color")
function drawRectangle() {
 let a = n.value
 let b = colors.value
 document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Every " + a + " rectangle is " + b;
 myShape();
 }
function myShape() {
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let x;
let y;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineTo(0,0);
ctx.lineTo(10,0);
ctx.lineTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(0,10);
ctx.lineTo(0,0);
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
ctx.strokeRect(0,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(10,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(20,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(30,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(40,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(50,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(60,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(70,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(80,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(90,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(100,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(110,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(120,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(130,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(140,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(150,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(160,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(170,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(180,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(190,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(200,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(210,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(220,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(230,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(240,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(250,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(260,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(270,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(280,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(290,0,10,10);
ctx.strokeRect(300,0,10,10);
}
document.getElementById("display").onclick = drawRectangle;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> CPSC 1045 Midterm 2 Practical Exam </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Let's Display Some Rectangles</h1>
<p>This application will diplay a series of rectangles on the screen, filling every Nth rectangle with the specified colour</p>
<p>Enter a number for N:<input type="number" id="number" max="30"></p>
<p>Enter the color: <input type="color" id="color"></p>
<button id="display">Display</button>
<p id="output">Output here</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" height="50" width="300" style="border: 1px solid black">
```

How do you get the value and color entered by the user and make every n-th rectangle the color entered by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array to make your rectangles, then use the Modulo operator to select each nth item in and paint it the color that the end user wants.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> CPSC 1045 Midterm 2 Practical Exam </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Let's Display Some Rectangles</h1>
    <p>This application will diplay a series of rectangles on the screen, filling every Nth rectangle with the specified
        colour</p>
    <p>Enter a number for N:<input type="number" id="number" max="30"></p>
    <p>Enter the color: <input type="color" id="color"></p>
    <button id="display">Display</button>
    <p id="output">Output here</p>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="50" width="300" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>

    <script> 
        let n = document.getElementById("number")
        let colors = document.getElementById("color")
        function drawRectangle() {
            let a = n.value
            let b = colors.value
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Every " + a + " rectangle is " + b;
            myShape(a, b);
            }
        function myShape(a, b) {
            let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            let x = 0;
            let y = 0;
            var rectArr = [];
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineTo(0,0);
            ctx.fillStyle = b;
            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                if (i%a == 0) {
                    ctx.fillRect(x, 0, 10, 10);
                    x += 10;
                } else {
                    ctx.strokeRect(x, 0, 10, 10);
                    x += 10;
                }
            }
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        document.getElementById("display").onclick = drawRectangle;
    
    </script>
            
</body>
</html>
```